# laravel-how to fetch Specified object in view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination, laravel-views

I'm passing data to the view and I'm trying to get a Certain key from a nested object without using foreach.
Help me to fetch the value of 'original' and '300' from images.

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 44,
            "user_id": 2,
            "title": "گزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویری",
            "slug": "گزارش-یک-برنامه-علمی-تصویری",
            "description": "گزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویری گزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویری گزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویری گزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویری",
            "body": "<p>گزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویریگزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویریگزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویریگزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویریگزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویریگزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویریگزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویریگزارش یک برنامه علمی تصویری</p>",
            "images": {
                "images": {
                    "300": "/upload/images/2018/300_gall1.jpg",
                    "600": "/upload/images/2018/600_gall1.jpg",
                    "900": "/upload/images/2018/900_gall1.jpg",
                    "original": "/upload/images/2018/gall1.jpg"
                },
                "thumb": "/upload/images/2018/300_gall1.jpg"
            },
            "tags": "گزارش تصویری",
            "viewCount": 0,
            "commentCount": 0,
            "created_at": "2018-11-01 09:25:58",
            "updated_at": "2018-11-01 09:25:58",
            "pivot": {
                "category_id": 8,
                "article_id": 44
            }
        }
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000?page=1",
    "next_page_url": null,
    "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "per_page": 1,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 1,
    "total": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it before you pass them to the view, with [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-get) helper function:

```
dd(array_get($data, 'data.images.images.300'), array_get($data, 'data.images.images.original'));
```

`$data` being your array.

Comment: I need to have all in view.

Comment: Are you using AJAX to fetch the data?

Comment: No. Its normal passing data to the view as compact.

Comment: then use the helper function within the view surrounded by `{{ }}` and it will be the same, if you don't want to iterate.

Comment: so how can i have access inside 'images'?

Comment: in your blade view, you can use php code, like this
`<img src="{{array_get($data, 'data.images.images.300')}}" alt="Image" />`